How to translate "frame challenge"?
In this site, it is quite common to see the word "frame challenge" in answers of questions. How to translate "frame challenge"?

I think you’re on the wrong site.

“Frame challenge” is Stack Exchange jargon

质疑假设 is probably the most apt. 挑战假设 also works if you want to maintain the "challenge" portion.

I have to know what it is to translate it, so I searched and got this:
What's a frame challenge?

A frame challenge is where an author answers a question in a wholly different way the querent never asked for, or potentially expressly forbade, but in a way the author feels will actually solve the problem.

A direct translation of "frame challenge" is 框架挑戰, which is quite understandable, instead of answering the question straight, you challenge the premise of the question itself

“Frame challenge” is Stack Exchange jargon

"Frame challenge" is not a familiar term for the general public. Only the regular users of this site know that "Frame" refers to the structure of a question.  you may have to provide a translation in layman's terms, for example,  "挑戰問題本身的另類答案" (Alternative answers that challenge the question itself)
Example:
Q: How do you specify past tense for 是?
A: "There's no need"

Would 腦洞大開 work? It doesn't capture the entire meaning of "frame challenge" but seems to be strangely appropriate.

腦洞大開 means "let imagination run wild" or "abnormal  mind"

Which means... the answer comes in from the left field

inductive argument
归纳论证
deductive argument
演绎论证; 推断论证
Everyone can see:

The sun rises in the East.
The sun sets in the West.

From these two facts we can both induce and deduce:
Therefore, the sun goes around the Earth.
Question: Why does the sun go around the Earth?
I would challenge your basic premises.
我质疑你的基本前提。
frame challenge: 质疑基本的前提

A Chinese equivalence to "frame challenge" is "突破思维框架", which means thinking without the limitation of the traditional ideology.

"frame challenge - 挑戰問題構架" - A frame challenge is an answer, comment (or part thereof) that doesn’t attempt to answer the question as is, but instead disputes things the asker treats as given in their question (challenges the frame/building blocks of the question).
https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4947/frame-challenge-guidelines-idea-collection
